# How to partly deobfuscate .NET binary?

Tags: python, c#, .net, deobfuscation

I have a piece of obfuscated code:

```
public static string P = "粹ताYwN의도==";

// Token: 0x06000038 RID: 56 RVA: 0x00004BF4 File Offset: 0x00002DF4
public static void u()
{
checked
   {
...
P = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(Strings.Replace(Strings.Replace(Strings.Replace(Strings.Replace(P, "粹", "M", 1, -1, CompareMethod.Binary), "ता", "T", 1, -1, CompareMethod.Binary), "의도", "A", 1, -1, CompareMethod.Binary), "에", "e", 1, -1, CompareMethod.Binary)));
...
}}
```

The questions are:

1. What is the basic approach to deobfuscate such strings?
2. Is it possible to somehow automate decrypting P variable? P might be encrypted in different ways, but always have assignment like "P = F(...)". F() does not depends on any external API. Moreover, it does not depend on any previous code. It even can be as simple as "P = 4".

Unfortunately I am limited by Linux. Also I can write code using Python/C. However, I'm also interesting if there is solution for Windows.

**UPDATE:**
I successfully using MIASM for emulating x86/x64 in some projects. So, I could get function execution result. Probably, I also need such kind of tool/framework.

Also, I'm aware of tools like de4dot and other deobfuscators. However, their directly execution did not help.

Comment: Regarding your tags: you say you can code in C, but you tagged C#. Also the deobfuscation tag is used for "Figuring out how a program works when that program has been deliberately made difficult to understand". Its not about decoding/encoding.

Comment: Yup. This binary is written in C#. I also could code using C#, but does this help on Linux? There are many kind of obfuscation exists. So, encoding with replacing is one of them. Obviously, you can't understand what is P.